# Magetno REST API - get product list with pagination

Tags: php, rest, magento-1.9

How to get product list with pagination using REST API ? I have following codes -

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');

$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product');
print_r($productCollection);
```

Output

```
[_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [entity_type_id] => 4
                    [entity_type_code] => catalog_product
                    [entity_model] => catalog/product
                    [attribute_model] => catalog/resource_eav_attribute
                    [entity_table] => catalog/product
                    [value_table_prefix] => 
                    [entity_id_field] => 
                    [is_data_sharing] => 1
                    [data_sharing_key] => default
                    [default_attribute_set_id] => 4
                    [increment_model] => 
                    [increment_per_store] => 0
                    [increment_pad_length] => 8
                    [increment_pad_char] => 0
                    [additional_attribute_table] => catalog/eav_attribute
                    [entity_attribute_collection] => catalog/product_attribute_collection
            )
```

Can anyone please help me.

**Update** as per your suggestion I have updated codes as -

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');

$pageSize = $_REQUEST['pagesize'];
$pageNum = $_REQUEST['pagenum'];

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->setPageSize($pageSize)
            ->setCurPage($pageNum )
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

print_r($productCollection->getData());
```

and the output is now -

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 12
            [entity_type_id] => 4
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => 20707
            [has_options] => 1
            [required_options] => 1
            [created_at] => 2016-01-06 21:15:31
            [updated_at] => 2016-10-03 00:49:21
        )
```

But still not able to get product name , description , image etc. Is there any other thing I am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Send the get parameters of pagesize and pagenum in your api request.

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');

$pageSize = $_GET['pagesize']
$pageNum = $_GET['pagenum']

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->setPageSize($pageSize)
            ->setCurPage($pageNum );

print_r($productCollection);
```

Comment: Thanks much Ravi for your reply , it is printing following array -  [0] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 12
            [entity_type_id] => 4
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => 20707
            [has_options] => 1
            [required_options] => 1
            [created_at] => 2016-01-06 21:15:31
            [updated_at] => 2016-10-03 00:49:21
        ) I need products related fields like , product name , description , image etc.

Comment: Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() ->addAttributeToSelect('sku') ->addAttributeToSelect('name')->setPageSize($pageSize) ->setCurPage($pageNum );

Comment: You can add any filed that you need using ->addAttributeToSelect('feildname') after getcollection()

Comment: I have updated code like - $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->setPageSize($pageSize)
            ->setCurPage($pageNum );

print_r($productCollection->getData()); but output is still same as above , no name field is added in the output.

Comment: This depends on your catalog settings try using addFieldToSelect instead of
addAttributeToSelect . addFieldToSelect is used for flat model ans addAttributeToSelect is used for EAV model

Comment: it is throwing error Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::addFieldToSelect()

Comment: Any other change I need to do Ravi ?

Comment: try using this addAttributeToSelect('*') once if this doesn't work try adding it after setCurPage() like this $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product') ->getCollection() ->setPageSize($pageSize) ->setCurPage($pageNum )->addAttributeToSelect('name');

Comment: try this for 1 last time $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->setPageSize($pageSize)
            ->setCurPage($pageNum )
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();

Comment: no luck Ravi :( , anyway +1 for your great effort. It is really appreciated. Thanks much and yes please post here if you found any other solution.